# is my partitioning scheme wrong?

Tags: partitioning, files, system, drive

I'm new to Linux so the root file system is not something im familiar with but allotted 20 Gb to it because I read that was sufficient and now I have less than 200 Mb left.

Is 20 Gb not enough? or is my scheme wrong? If I remember correctly, you can get to the user folder through root so wouldn't it be pointless setting up a different mount point for `/` (root) and one for the user (`/home`)?

Under my disk usage analyzer, it showed me where most of the space was going but I'm not sure what could be there to take up this much room. Can someone tell me what could possibly be in these folders to take up so much room?

[photo link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UVyA.jpg)

The output of `df -h` https://pastebin.com/embed_js/TDU82LMP

```
TDU82LMP

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           751M  3.3M  747M   1% /run
/dev/sda2        19G   17G  523M  98% /
tmpfs           3.7G  482M  3.2G  13% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/335
/dev/loop3       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop1       16M   16M     0 100% /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/420
/dev/loop4       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop2      8.7M  8.7M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/84
/dev/loop6       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/remmina/3223
/dev/loop10     128K  128K     0 100% /snap/software-boutique/39
/dev/loop7      8.0M  8.0M     0 100% /snap/pulsemixer/250
/dev/loop8      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/97
/dev/loop9       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1223
/dev/loop5      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/94
/dev/loop12      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/discord/93
/dev/loop13     8.7M  8.7M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/88
/dev/loop11     5.9M  5.9M     0 100% /snap/htop/1168
/dev/loop14      89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop16     150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
/dev/loop15     157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/91
/dev/sda3       436G   99G  315G  24% /home
tmpfs           751M   20K  751M   1% /run/user/124
tmpfs           751M   52K  751M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Lots of stuff could be there, but there is no way to know, without you providing detailed info. 20GB may or may not be sufficient, it depends on individual needs and usage. You should add the output of `df -h` to the question.

Comment: Apparently, the 19GB system partition (aka root partition) is too small for you. The size of 19GB is not wrong, it is just not suitable for what you need. Having separate / and /home is not a requirement, in fact, the automated Ubuntu installer doesn't do it.

Comment: ok, thank you for adjusting that, i still can not figure out how to do that embedding code thing. so i thought that may be the case so when i go to gparted and try to shrink my larger partition to increase the root it wont allow me. so i tried to unmount it because i thought that was why it wouldn't allow me and it says its in use. so how can i increase the size?

Comment: You cannot change mounted partitions. if you have tiny key icon it is mounted. You normally use a live installer to modify / (root) or any other partitions that would normally be mounted, like your /home. Be sure to have good backups. You may have to move partition and any interruption will cause data loss. And moving larger partition can take a long time. RecoverLostDiskSpace
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoverLostDiskSpace Also snaps now take more space than a .deb if available.

Comment: Look like you are saving stuff in / instead of /home. Or perhaps your /home is unmounted.

Comment: i feel like that may be the case too, is there any way to know for sure? i download everything to my downloads folder but wouldn't it be better to just have everything in one partition rather than separating home and root?

Comment: Try the command du -s /* 2>/dev/null  to see a top level summary of where the space is being used. /snap and /var take about 10G on my system alone.

Comment: @Josh /dev/sda2 is really small; 19GB, and since snaps recreate a lot of the system within them, you will need more space for / (AKA 'root'). /dev/sda3 is really big and you could take space from it and put it in /dev/sda2 using gparted http://gparted.org .  However, more info will help us plan it better, because I don't see /dev/sda1; is this a dual-boot machine? Please run `sudo parted print` thne click [edit] and paste the results into your question. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].